# Extract a special hash from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract the following pattern `{#56DS1e5R9w7v}` which is :

- **{**
- **Hash**
- **a-z, A-Z, 0-9** ( not necessarily an alphanumeric string )
- **}**

Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: In what way is a-z A-Z 0-9 "not necessarily an alphanumeric string"?

Comment: Means it may be only numbers or characters or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
\{#([^}]*)\}
```

It should match all characters that are not `}`, and place the result in a captured group. You *may* want to change `[^}]*` to `\w*` or `[A-Za-z0-9]*` if that's problematic.

Example ([also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3si80)):

```
$str = "hello {#56DS1e5R9w7v} good people";
preg_match_all("/\{#([^}]*)\}/", $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like ({#[a-z0-9]+?}) ?

```
preg_match('/(\{#[a-z0-9]+?\})/i', $sString)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
 <?php

     $code = '{#56DS1e5R9w7v}';
     $matches = preg_match('/^\{#[a-zA-Z0-9]+\}$/', $code); 

 ?>
```

This makes sure the string begins with a `{` the second char must be a `#`, the 3th char until `}` must be alpha numeric and it must end with a `}`.

Hope this helped!